# Computer does not boot to Fedora but to Shim UEFI key management instead

Tags: fedora, boot

When I turn on my computer, Fedora (which is the only OS installed on this computer does not boot). Instead, the following is printed to the screen:

```
System BootOrder. Initializing defaults.
Creating boot entry "Boot0120" with label "Fedora" for file "\EFI\fedora\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load Image \EFI\fedora\grubx64.efi: Not found
```

After what appears a blue window which title is "Shim UEFI key management". It says:

```
Press any key to perform MOK management
```

At its bottom, there is a countdown

```
Booting in x seconds
```

with x going from 10 to 1.

Fedora versions which are on my computer are the 24, and I believe three other 23, from what I remember.

I don't remember having installed a new software recently.

The first time this problem happened, as I just turned on my computer and didn't look on the screen, I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, because normally my computer asks me for the version of Fedora I want to use. If I press the alimentation button, my computer goes off immediately.

How can I make my computer boot to Fedora again?